# AVCaptureSession Low Preview Quality

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

My app uses video recording, and so I use the AVCaptureSession. When I see the Capture Session preview, however, I notice that the quality is lower, especially when pointing the camera over text on a television or computer screen. How can I increase the quality of my Capture Session so that it will display text on computer screens more clearly? This is the part of my code that deals with video quality.

```
self.CaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.CaptureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
[self.CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
//----- ADD INPUTS -----

//ADD VIDEO INPUT
self.VideoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([self.VideoDevice hasTorch] == YES){
    self.flashSet.hidden = NO;
    self.flashOverlayObject.hidden = NO;
}
[self.VideoDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
[self.VideoDevice setAutoFocusRangeRestriction:AVCaptureAutoFocusRangeRestrictionNear];
[self.VideoDevice setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
[self.VideoDevice setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];
[self.VideoDevice setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance];
if(self.VideoDevice.lowLightBoostSupported){
    self.VideoDevice.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = YES;
}
[self.VideoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
if (self.VideoDevice)
{
    NSError *error;
    self.VideoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.VideoDevice error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {
        if ([self.CaptureSession canAddInput:self.VideoInputDevice])
            [self.CaptureSession addInput:self.VideoInputDevice];
    }

}
```